# Average of an autocorrelation

Tags: stochastic-processes, correlation

I am struggling with a random process problem.  I have a sequence of random variables, $a_i$, where $a_i$ is either -1 or 1 with 50% probability.  I am studying realisations of the magnitude of the autocorrelation, eg.:
$$\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix},\quad R_A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & -2 & -1\\
\end{bmatrix} \mathrm{and} \quad\left|R_A\right|=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 1 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
My main objective is to develop a relationship that gives the average value of each element of the magnitude autocorrelation.  For this question, I can find via brute force that the average is,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & 4 & \frac{3}{2} & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I would appreciate any pointers on how to show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the vector has length $m$ then the central correlation is always $m$.
Otherwise it depends on the number, say $n$, of overlapping $A_i$.
If $n$ is even, then the final term is equally likely to increase or decrease $R_A$, so the average value is the same as for $n-1$.
If $n$ is odd, it is similar, except if the sum of the first $n-1$ terms is zero, in which case the final term increases $R_A$.  This happens with probability $\frac1{2^{n-1}}{n-1\choose (n-1)/2}$, so the average is that much bigger.
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}4^{-k}{2k\choose k}$$

Comment: This is a remarkably elegant result.  I have seen what you described empirically.  I am going to have to pull the probability $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ ${n-1}\choose{(n-1)/2}$ apart carefully to try and understand it better - that part is not quite clear, but this is a great help.